# Accidentally deleted active_plugins portion of the wp_options DB table

Tags: database, options, phpmyadmin

Ok, so I'm pretty sure I'm screwed here, because I do not have a database backup, but I figured I'd ask just in case.

Within PhpMyAdmin, I meant to just go to the wp_options table and empty out active_plugins portion of this table due to not being about to login because of a plugin error. Well I hit the delete button instead of just emptying it out.

Is there any way I can manually add in the active_plugins part of this table?

I tried the repair database thing, but that didn't work.

Comment: A missing `active_plugins` row should not prevent login. I just tested with a brand new 3.6 install. You must have done more damage than just that.

Answer (score 2):

Just log back into your admin, go to Plugins, and reactivate each of the plugins you use.

Comment: Well that's the issue. I can't login at all

Comment: A plugin needed an update, but we couldn't login or access the site at all, so that's why I meant to go in an empty out just the active_plugins row, but deleted it altogether on accident.

Comment: Hmmmm, ok well their host actually has a backup, so I'm attempting to use that. Fingers crossed.

Comment: insert row for active_plugins , it will be empty obviously

Answer (score 1):

Using the FTP of cPanel's File Manager, just get into `root/wp-content/plugins` and select all the plugins and **move** them on step *up*, so the `plugins` folder will be empty.

Clear the browser cache, and try to get into the Admin panel.

Doing this WordPress won't try to initiate any of your plugins, and you know plugins are additional to WordPress, not mandatory.

Once you entered into the Admin panel, everything's set.

Now get to `roor/wp-content/` and select all your plugins, (remember there are other folders like `themes`, `uploads` etc. there - don't select them) and move them back into the `wp-content/plugins` folder.

From admin panel get to the Plugins menu, and reactivate all your plugins (because with the first step you disabled 'em all).

Hope that helps.